# The position that I have applied is being advertised again. Should I be worried?

Tags: job-search

I am interviewing within a couple of days for a position. As far as I know, that position has been rejected by at least one candidate before me.

I know why the position was declined in the past, this aspect of the job was discussed with me.
However, I just realized that the College has started to advertise the position again on the usual academic job boards.

Should I be worried about this? Is this something that was mandated by the people leading the search or something that HR Departments do on their own?
If anyone with insights on this process could give some perspective that'd be great.

Comment: "Again"? They took the ad down and then put it back up?  Normally ads would stay up until a candidate had accepted an offer in writing.

Comment: My mistake. The ad was initially posted on another board a while ago. It expired there, but now it can be found on a different board as well and it was posted recently from what I can gather.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Should I be worried about this?

Nope. It is totally out of your control and impossible to guess what it means. It could mean they have already written you off and are just wasting time (and money) bringing you in for an interview. It could also mean that they are hopeful about you and need to satisfy some HR requirement. It could also mean lots of other things.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why they could be hopeful about me, and meeting HR requirements? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: They might think you are worth bringing to campus and interviewing and hoping that they will make you an offer (this seems reasonable since they invited you for an interview). HR may have told them they need to relist the job after the earlier search failed. They may be simply saving time by not requiring you (and everyone else) to reapply. Again, just ignore it and keep preparing for the interview.

Comment: Thank you, StrongBad! Been preparing for this interview for days and your post just gave me hope, since it does make sense. But as you mentioned, who knows. All I can do is prepare and do my best during the interview. Cheers.

Comment: @fuji-phd welcome to AC.SE. You should take a look at our [help]. If my answer is helpful, you can give me an upvote (and eventually accept the answer). Good luck on the interview.

Comment: Some universities have a policy of interviewing "not less than 3, not more than 5 external candidates". What happens when you have only 2 strong externals? Free trip to someone, just to fill the numbers.... Been there, nice hotel at least..... (just as an illustration of possible absurd scenario)

Comment: They have started calling my references. I don’t know what to think anymore. The academic market is very unpredictable!

Answer (score 0):

Basically yes. This is how I would interpret things in the job world.  (Have had the exact experience.)  And this is more of a job world issue than a pure academia one.  (No worries, mods, still fits the forum.)

They might still be holding on to you as a deep fall back.  But when they send a new request out, it almost always means they don't like who they have seen so far.

All that said, you need to have a gazillion hooks in the water and not pay too much attention to one until it is very serious.  Keep prospecting.